# Ubuntu won't boot from usb - Windows 8 - non dual boot related

Tags: usb, preinstallation

I'm trying to replace Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu. I understand there are dual boot issues. I would like to completely replace Windows. I have created a usb installer as directed, but cannot get it to boot. Only Windows boot menu appears on the boot menu.

I attempted to change the BIOS to legacy, but the only option is UEFI.

My computer is Packard Bell EasyNoteTE69BM

Comment: Did you turn secure boot off?  That sometimes helps.  It was necessary on an Asus X200.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it won't be easy on your hardware, according to [this thread (post #8 and forward)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2189855). The easiest solution is to install from the netboot image.

Answer (score 0):

Because this problem doesn't have an eminently easy software-based solution, I'm here to offer a hardware-based one.

If at all possible, grab the HDD out of your laptop (one of the participants in the thread FourZer0 linked to mentions an Amazon review saying it's fairly straightforward if you're willing to poke around). Now, not knowing very much about Packard-Bell, I'm going to assume they didn't reinvent the wheel in the interest of pleasing Microsoft, and are using the standard SATA HDD connection. Slide you HDD out and swap it for one in another machine (laptop or desktop, won't really matter) and install from there with your "unsecure BIOS" then drop it back in your laptop.

I would warn that if the BIOS is really that locked out, it may be looking for Windows to boot, so I wouldn't go erasing Windows before you boot on your laptop- you can do that later anyway.

I realize this isn't the most elegant way to go about things, and may be inconvenient for you, but it does appear the simplest way to me, at least.